# Javascript - Extend this.value within a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

First of all I know i can just move the whole file out of vendor, and update where needed. This is what i've currently done, however i'm just curious of if there is a way to do this without the current solution.

I have some vendor JS as seen below. Is there a way that i can alter the `this.init` function within the function if i only have access to the app.test variable? So replace the this.init function with my own function?

```
app.test = function(){
  this.init = function(){
   some code here that calls other this.functions that use jquery
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Original code:

```js
app.test = function(){
  this.init = function(){
   // some code here that calls other this.functions that use jquery
  }
}
```

---

There is a specific JS feature used that is called "constructor function" (used with operator `new`):

```js
CustomObject = function() {
  // this = {}; // Implicitly defines `this`

  this.init = function() {
    console.log("INIT");
  }

  // return this; // Implicitly returns `this`
}

// Alternative way to do the same
function CustomObject2() {
  this.init = function() {
    console.log("INIT");
  }
}
```

This code:

1. Creates a constructor `CustomObject` which can be called later with operator `new`: `x = new CustomObject()`.
2. When called with `new`, creates an object and sets its properties/methods. Everything is defined using `this.` in the constructor function.
3. Properties/methods will work in the context of created object.

Therefore, solution is to replace the whole constructor with a new one:

1. Call original constructor.
2. Replace `init()` with new implementation in the created object.
3. Return "hacked" object.

---

See the snippet:

```js
// Prepare
app = {};
app.test = {};

// Code from the original question
app.test = function() {

  this.init = function() {
    console.log("ORIGINAL");
    this.doWork();
  }
  
  // Another method
  this.doWork = function() {
    console.log("WORK");
  }
}

// Testing out
console.log("Test #1 - Original");
var test1 = new app.test();
test1.init(); // ORIGINAL, WORK
console.log("");

// Saving old constructor function
oldAppTest = app.test;

// Creating new one
app.test = function() {
    // Calling old constructor
  result = new oldAppTest();
  // Replacing `init()` in the created object
  result.init = function() {
    console.log("NEW");
    // Call another method from the object
    result.doWork();
  }
  // Returning from constructor function
  return result;
}

// Testing out
console.log("Test #2 - Hacked init()");
var test2 = new app.test();
test2.init(); // NEW, WORK
```

> Useful links:
>
> - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new
> - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_constructors.asp

Comment: Unfortunatley not, if you remove the new `app.test.init = function()` from your example, trying the app.test.init(); will not work as this is not a function or defined.

Comment: You are right, it doesn't work. I'll remove the answer

Comment: @Ashler2, I came up with the working answer

Comment: @Ashler2, do you mind accepting the answer if out solves your problem